# Property of positive-definite Matrix

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

Suppose $M\succ0$ and also suppose that $$0<x^TMx <y^TMy.$$

Can I say the following $$x^TMx<x^TMy <y^TMy?$$

Thanks!

Comment: No. The middle one may be nonpositive. For example, take $M=I$ and $y=-2x$

Comment: If $x = y = 0$, then $0 = x^TMx = y^TMy$. Quantifiers, please.